# c# how to: define a long string with linebreaks?

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there a way to define a single long string with line breaks within the string definition code?

my string is somethign like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT 
                     a.bg_user_56 AS Project, 
                     a.bg_user_60 AS SubSystem, 
                     a.BG_USER_81 AS AssignedToUserName, 
                     a.bg_responsible AS AssignedTo,  
              FROM mytable"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a verbatim string literal (that begins with a `@`):

```
string sql = @"SELECT 
                     a.bg_user_56 AS Project, 
                     a.bg_user_60 AS SubSystem, 
                     a.BG_USER_81 AS AssignedToUserName, 
                     a.bg_responsible AS AssignedTo,  
              FROM mytable"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = @"SELECT a.bg_user_56 AS Project,\r\na.bg_user_60 AS SubSystem,\r\na.BG_USER_81 AS AssignedToUserName,\r\na.bg_responsible AS AssignedTo,\r\nFROM mytable"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
string sql = @"MyNiceCleanStoredProc @Param";
```

Answer (score 0):

The @ sign is great for this, but for SQL, I like to define my SQL as a project resource. This makes it easy to read, update, and open in Query Analyzer (or the T-Sql editor of you choice) and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Use @ as

```
string s=@"Hello
           This is
           StackOverflow";
```